# How is widget being updated in Android(using AlarmManager)

Tags: java, android, widget, android-widget

My app uses a widget which I want to get updatet on particular times throughout a day. Here's the  code:

```
package com.apps.app;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

import com.snappydb.DB;
import com.snappydb.DBFactory;
import com.snappydb.SnappydbException;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

public static String ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_WIDGET = "ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_WIDGET";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    if (ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_WIDGET.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Log.d("widget","received");
        onUpdate(context, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context),
                AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, Widget.class)));
    }
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    super.onDisabled(context);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Widget.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_WIDGET);
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmMgr.cancel(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0));
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    super.onEnabled(context);

    try {
        DB db = DBFactory.open(context, "notes");
        ArrayList <Note> noteArrayList = db.getObject("notes", ArrayList.class);
        for(Note note: noteArrayList) {
            setUpdateIntent(context, note.getHours(), note.getMinutes());
        }
    } catch (SnappydbException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}

private void setUpdateIntent(Context context, int h, int m) {
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, Widget.class);
    intent1.setAction(ACTION_AUTO_UPDATE_WIDGET);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, h*m, intent1, 0);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, m);

    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, c.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
    for (int id : appWidgetIds) {
        updateWidget(context, appWidgetManager, id);
    }
}

private void updateWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager manager, int widgetId) {
    RemoteViews widgetView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
    widgetView.setTextViewText(R.id.dateTextView, TimeManager.getDay());
    widgetView.setTextViewText(R.id.curTimeTextView, TimeManager.getTime());
    widgetView.setTextViewText(R.id.weatherTextView,
            context.getSharedPreferences("weather", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString("weather", "default"));

    Intent configIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    configIntent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE);
    configIntent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, widgetId, configIntent, 0);
    widgetView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.layoutId, pIntent);

    manager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, widgetView);
}

}
```

Based on DB's data, it should get updated exactly on 17:37, 17:40 and 17:42.
And here's my update log:

```
2021-09-07 17:38:31.518 6787-6787/com.apps.app D/widget: received
2021-09-07 17:38:31.547 6787-6787/com.apps.app D/widget: received
2021-09-07 17:42:52.078 6787-6787/com.apps.app D/widget: received
2021-09-07 17:42:52.092 6787-6787/com.apps.app D/widget: received
```

I don't really understand on what algorithm widget's update is based. Can someone explain it to me?

Comment: Could you share the entire class, what it extends from, etc?

Comment: It is not caused by widget update. In fact, the alarm is inexact.

Answer (score 0):

If your application wants to allow the delivery times to drift in order to guarantee that at least a certain time interval always elapses between alarms, then the approach to take is to use one-time alarms, scheduling the next one yourself when handling each alarm delivery.

As of API 19, all repeating alarms are inexact. If your application needs precise delivery times then it must use one-time exact alarms, rescheduling each time as described above. Legacy applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to have all of their alarms, including repeating alarms, treated as exact.